# validating form with multiple form tag using bootstrap formvalidators

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-validate

I have a form with some fields, and also another form inside the same form ,
I want to validate upper form and inner form respectively,
for eg:

```
<form name="upperFORM" ID="upperFORM" >
              <div class="form-control-group">
                <label class="control-label" for="email">Email Address</label>
                <div class="controls">
                  <input type="text" class="input-xlarge" name="email" id="email">
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-control-group">
                <label class="control-label" for="message">Your Address</label>
                <div class="controls">
                  <textarea class="input-xlarge" name="address" id="address" rows="3"></textarea>
                </div>
              </div>
    <form name="innerForm" id="innerForm" >
     <div class="form-control-group">
                <label class="control-label" for="name">Your Name</label>
                <div class="controls">
                  <input type="text" class="input-xlarge" name="name" id="name">
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="form-control-group">
                <label class="control-label" for="name">User Name</label>
                <div class="controls">
                  <input type="text" class="input-xlarge" name="username" id="username">
                </div>
              </div>
    </form>

</form>
```

jquery validation:

```
$('#upperFORM').validate({
    rules: {
        email: {
            required: true,
            required: true
        },

        address: {
            minlength: 6,
            required: true
        }



    },
    highlight: function (element) {
        $(element).closest('.control-group').removeClass('success').addClass('error');
    },
    success: function (element) {
        element
        .text('OK!').addClass('valid')
        .closest('.control-group').removeClass('error').addClass('success');
    }
});

    $('#innerForm').validate({
        rules: {
            name: {
                required: true,
                required: true
            },

            username: {
                minlength: 6,
                required: true
            }



        },
        highlight: function (element) {
            $(element).closest('.control-group').removeClass('success').addClass('error');
        },
        success: function (element) {
            element
            .text('OK!').addClass('valid')
            .closest('.control-group').removeClass('error').addClass('success');
        }
    });
```

the above code is not working,please help

Answer (score 1):

> I have a form with some fields, and also another form inside the same form , I want to validate upper form and inner form respectively.

```
<form name="upperFORM" ID="upperFORM" >
    ....
    <form name="innerForm" id="innerForm" >
        ....
    </form>
</form>
```

You **cannot and should not** do this.

- The jQuery Validate plugin will not be able to properly handle a `<form>` inside of a `<form>`.  It was written to work with valid HTML markup.
- It's invalid HTML.  There is no such thing as having a nested `form`.
- It really makes no sense.  There is no good reason to have a nested `form`.

---

You never explained what you're trying to accomplish by nesting `form` containers, but the only way jQuery Validate will work on these is by separating the two.

```
<form name="upperFORM" ID="upperFORM" >....</form>

<form name="innerForm" id="innerForm" >....</form>
```

Whatever it is that you're trying to accomplish by nesting two forms, could likely be accomplished better through other means.